# PowerApps auto numbering

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I wish to add the numbering by +1  but need to do like below

First Record = MBO0000001

next record = MBO0000002

Sample Code:

```
Text(Value(Last(Filter(SOP10100,SOPNUMBE = SOGALLERY.Selected.SOPNUMBE)).SOPNUMBE+1),"MBO#,#######")
```

any idea of how doing it? Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the number by using the Right() function, and strip the first 3 characters (being the "MBO"). Then add one and format it with the rest of the characters.

```
Text(Right(ThisItem.TestNumber3,Len(ThisItem.TestNumber3)-3)+1,"MBO0000000")
```

[image]